# Unexpected identifier in node.js and I can't seem to trace it

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, github-api

Here is my code:

```
github.repos.getContent({

user: "vydingding",
repo: "vydingding.github.io",
path: "_data/faculty.csv"
}, function(err, res) {
pastfile = res.sha;
response.json({ message: 'Successful! Sha: ' +  res.sha}); 

github.repos.updateFile({

var public_spreadsheet_url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Etze7fBNH3j4ss4-LPz_-khYRKnh0w34ScsqaJDvXtE/pubhtml';

var tabletop = Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url, callback: showInfo, simpleSheet: true } )

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

var fields = ['Faculty Name', 'Age'];

json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
  if 
  (err) console.log(err);
  data = csv;

});

data = new Buffer(data.toString('base64'));
buff = data.toString('base64');      

user: "vydingding",
repo: "vydingding.github.io",
path: "_data/faculty.csv",
message: "Faculty list change",
content: buff
sha: pastfile
}}, function(err, res) {
response.json({ message: 'Update file successful!'});   
});
});
```

And it says that the line:

```
var public_spreadsheet_url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Etze7fBNH3j4ss4-LPz_-khYRKnh0w34ScsqaJDvXtE/pubhtml';
```

has an unexpected identifier. I tried tracing it and I cannot find the unexpected identifier. How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The line before it is invalid:

```
github.repos.updateFile({
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a clear syntax error and can be **FIXED** very easily as:

Just put following part of code above this line `github.repos.updateFile({` and all will be okay.

```
var public_spreadsheet_url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Etze7fBNH3j4ss4-LPz_-khYRKnh0w34ScsqaJDvXtE/pubhtml';

var tabletop = Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url, callback: showInfo, simpleSheet: true } )

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

var fields = ['Faculty Name', 'Age'];

json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
  if 
  (err) console.log(err);
  data = csv;

});

data = new Buffer(data.toString('base64'));
buff = data.toString('base64');
```

**Edit** Still there are syntax errors I have fixed for you, following is complete fixed version of your code:

```
github.repos.getContent({
    user: "vydingding",
    repo: "vydingding.github.io",
    path: "_data/faculty.csv"
}, function (err, res) {
    pastfile = res.sha;
    response.json({message: 'Successful! Sha: ' + res.sha});

    var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Etze7fBNH3j4ss4-LPz_-khYRKnh0w34ScsqaJDvXtE/pubhtml';

    var tabletop = Tabletop.init({key: public_spreadsheet_url, callback: showInfo, simpleSheet: true})

    function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var fields = ['Faculty Name', 'Age'];
        json2csv({data: data, fields: fields}, function (err, csv) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            data = csv;
        });
        data = new Buffer(data.toString('base64'));
        buff = data.toString('base64');
    }

    github.repos.updateFile({

            user: "vydingding",
            repo: "vydingding.github.io",
            path: "_data/faculty.csv",
            message: "Faculty list change",
            content: buff
            sha: pastfile
        }
        ,
        function (err, res) {
            response.json({message: 'Update file successful!'});
        });
});
```